# How to tame the wild MMA?

Tags: function-construction, upvalues

MMA is a free country. But TOO free sometimes.

Just as an example:

```
Clear[a]
a[x_] == a[y_] ^:= Round[x] == Round[y]
{a[3] == a[3.01], a[3] == a[4]}
```

is {True, False}.
However,

```
{a[3] != a[3.01], a[3] != a[4]}
```

is NOT {False, True}.
Of course I have to define for Unequal[].
MMA is flexible, but too much in some situation.

So, I want a "prison". Does the prison such as guidelines or "Eq class" exist ?

ps. sorry for my poor english.

Comment: What do you really need? Is `a[x_]:=Round@x` or `(b : Equal | Unequal)[a[x_], a[y_]] ^:= b[Round[x], Round[y]]` satisfying? BTW, what's your first language?

Comment: @asoldat What do you mean saying that `{a[3] != a[3.01], a[3] != a[4]}` is NOT {False, True} ? If you don't define the `UpSetDelayed` for `Unequal` the result for `{a[3] != a[3.01], a[3] != a[4]}` is `{a[3] != a[3.01], a[3] != a[4]}`

Comment: As Guido notes, I would not consider this behavior wild: the behavior was only defined with respect to just **one** symbol, and *Mathematica* respected that. Thus, you have at least six relational operators to deal with, as well as `Inequality[]`.

Comment: `eqClass = {Equal, SameQ, Unequal, UnsameQ, Less, LessEqual, Greater, 
   GreaterEqual};
ClearAll[a];
a /: h_[a[x_], a[y_]] /; MemberQ[eqClass, h] := h[Round[x], Round[y]];
{a[3] == a[3.01], a[3] != a[4]}` would be a way to go, but there's probably something being lost in translation here?

Comment: @R.M.  the eqClass which ive wanted. Any other "class" in MMA ?

Comment: @J.M. "wild" is the wrong word. i would say "free spirit".

Comment: Not even close. I'd say the thing "only does what it's told and no more." Anyway, R.M. covered the lot of it, except for `Inequality[]`.

Comment: @xzczd I want  "class list", one of which is the eqClass that R.M. wrote. and im japanese.

Comment: @J.M What you mentioned is exactly called "free spirit" in japanese. What a miracle.

Comment: Oh okay. The phrase connotes something different in English see. To go back to this situation, it'd be like setting things for `Equal` and suddenly having behavior towards `Inequality` as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your definition

```
a[x_] == a[y_] ^:= Round[x] == Round[y]
```

Is *structural*. It tells *Mathematica* how to rewrite certain expressions. It has no mathematical meaning. Mathematica has no mechanism to infer mathematical meaning from the rewrite rules you provide. It cannot determine what mathematical consistency might mean for your symbols. Rewrite rules are not mathematics, but the material you use to construct mathematics. So, you must provide all of the necessary definitions to make your symbols behave as you wish.

R. M.'s comment (which should really be an answer) is a clever way to represent all of the necessary definitions in one definition for this case.